# Showing that a subset of real vector space is a subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$$ \{p ∈ P(\mathbb R) : p(2) = 1\}$$

I'm not really sure on the procedure to solve it. I know I need to show that it contains the $0_{V}$ and is closed under addition and scalar multiplication, but how do I go about doing that?

Comment: How do you add two polynomials? Is the zero polynomial in this set? What did you try?

Comment: Two things; 1) Always put the question in the body of the question, not just in the title. 2) My guess is that you meant “subspace”, not “subset”.

Comment: No I meant subset, and I'm not sure how to show that it even contains the $0_{V}$ edit: Oh didnt see the second subset I used.

Comment: A subset is a subset is a subset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check whether or not some specific object $a$ is contained in a set given by set-builder notation

$$ \{ x \in S \mid P(x) \} $$

where $P(x)$ stands for some logical proposition in terms of $x$, you do the following procedure:

- Check if $a \in S$
- Check if $P(a)$ is true

If both of these are true, then $a$ is a member of this set. If either of these are false, then $a$ is not a member of this set.

---

Substituting the given problem into this general procedure, to check if

$$ 0_V \in \{p \in P(\mathbb R) : p(2) = 1\}$$

you need to check

- Check if $0_V \in P(\mathbb{R})$
- Check if $0_V(2) = 1$